# How to give edges different colors in prefuse visualization toolkit

Tags: visualization, prefuse

I am using prefuse, and I would like to know how to give different colors to different edges?

For example, I generate a graph which has 5 nodes from a XML file. Their numbers are 0,1,2,3,4. In the program, I want the edge of which the start node is 3 and the end node is 4 to be colored red, and other nodes be colored other colors. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a color action for `VisualItem.STROKECOLOR` and give it the edge-group as a key, possibly with a predicate if you want to assign that colour only to certain edges

```scala
new ColorAction(GROUP_EDGES, (myPredicate, ) VisualItem.STROKECOLOR, myColor)
```